# Rewriting a line of VB code to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel

How would I write the 3rd VB code in C#?.  I can't find anything on Google.

```vb
Imports XL = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class LicenseRenewal

    ' The line below to C#
    Private xlRangesForRenewal As New List(Of XL.Range)
```

Thanks in Advance and Happy Friday!

Comment: What have you tried exactly?  I have to downvote this question since the author appears to have done no research whats so ever.  I was able to find code within 30 seconds by doing a google search.

Comment: Ramhound,  I've been tasked with converting a project in VB to C#.  Although the answer may have been easy for you to find, it was hard for me because I am less experienced (never took an IT class).  Therefore, when googling, I do not know exactly what to put.  Where as on this forum, I am able to copy and paste my code and talk in human terms what I am looking for without the Technology verbage.  I am not very good at this which is why I pay for a subscription for help.  If you are so smart that my question seems stupid to you than you are very fortunate in having the expertise and knowledge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

alexn was nearly there, but you *either* need a using alias directive:

```
using XL = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public class LicenseRenewal {
  private List<XL.Range> xlRangesForRenewal = new List<XL.Range>();
}
```

Or you can just use the namespace without an alias, but adjust the usage accordingly:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public class LicenseRenewal {
  private List<Range> xlRangesForRenewal = new List<Range>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public class LicenseRenewal {
  private List<XL.Range> xlRangesForRenewal = new List<XL.Range>();
}
```

Should do it.

Comment: You might want to declare what **XL** is.

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<XL.Range> xlRangesForRenewal = new List<XL.Range>();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good convertor for vb to C# and vice versa and provides the same answer to your selected answer:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: OMG! Thank you sooo much for this! You are an angel O:)

Answer (score 0):

```
using XL = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;     

public class LicenseRenewal {     
    var xlRangesForRenewal = new List<XL.Range>();     
}
```